# Custom Json Deserializer

Tags: c#, json

I would like to create a custom JSON Deserializer that can map json below to the C# class, any advise, help or pointers to relevant resources will be appreciated.
Thanks

```
{   
   "PersonId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
   "Name": "XXXXXXXX",  
   "HobbiesCollection":
        {"Hobby":
            [
                {
                    "type": "RUNNING",
                    "id": 44,
                    "description": "sprinting and sprinting?"
                },
                {
                    "type": "RUNNING",
                    "id": 45,
                    "description": "jogging and jogging"
                }
            ]
        }   
}
```

```
public class OtherStuff
{
    public OtherStuff(IList<Hobby> hobbyList)
    {            
        HobbyList = hobbyList;
    }


    public IList<Hobby> HobbyList
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to create your own deserializer? Can't you use an existing one, like JSON.NET ?

Comment: I purely want to create a custom deserializer for learning purposes only, rather than recreating the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use an existing library. The most famous one is Json.Net
http://james.newtonking.com/json

You can also write your own deserializer , but using an existing library is much easier.

Answer (score 0):

You can try simple JSON to do this , its just .CS file and simple to use. (no dll reference)

https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/simple-json

http://www.nuget.org/packages/SimpleJson/